# Sitecore, user doesn't have "Insert External Link, Insert Media Link, etc." when updating a General Link field

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

In Sitecore 8.0, I have a user who doesn't have "Insert External Link, Insert Media Link, etc." when updating a General Link field.   She just sees a text field to enter a link.

I looked in the Core database with Access Viewer and her user account has Read access to all the items under "System > Field Types > Link Types > General Link < Menu"

Any idea why this is so?   I can see the options fine under my admin-level account.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recently i faced similar issue, when "**non-admin**" user can't see any buttons on link field, It turned out the the item template was using the deprecated "**Link**" field type instead of "**General Link**", That could be the cause of the issue.

Comment: This was it.   The particular item template was using the Link field.   Corrected this and now the non admin user can see the buttons.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the user has ticked the `Raw Values` checkbox in the View ribbon.

[image]

Make sure that field is not ticked and the options should appear again.